# How to convert Microsoft Recurring Pattern DaysOfWeekMask to a RRULE string

Tags: vba, outlook, bit-manipulation, recurring, appointment

I have Outlook VBA code which runs when a recurring event is added to a calendar.  I need to convert the event.GetRecurrencePattern.DaysOfWeekMask to a valid Rrule string.

I am creating a weekly recurring event which occurs every Sunday, Tuesday, and Friday for 10 occurrences.

When the event is added, this code gets executed:

```
    If Item.IsRecurring = True Then
        Set ItemRecurrPatt = Item.GetRecurrencePattern
        RRuleFrequency = ConvertFrequency(ItemRecurrPatt.RecurrenceType)
        RRuleByDay = ConvertDaysOfTheWeek(ItemRecurrPatt.DayOfWeekMask)
    End If
```

ConvertFrequency is correctly returning "Weekly" so I don't have a problem with that function.

This is the code for ConvertDaysOfTheWeek:

```
Function ConvertDaysOfTheWeek(ByVal DayMask As Integer) As String

    Dim sDaysOfTheWeek As String
    sDaysOfTheWeek = ""

    If (DayMask & OlDaysOfWeek.olSunday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = ",SU"
    End If

    If (DayMask & OlDaysOfWeek.olMonday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",MO"
    End If
 
    If (DayMask & OlDaysOfWeek.olTuesday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",TU"
    End If

    If (DayMask & OlDaysOfWeek.olWednesday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",WE"
    End If

    If (DayMask & OlDaysOfWeek.olThursday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",TH"
    End If
 
    If (DayMask & OlDaysOfWeek.olFriday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",FR"
    End If
 
    If (DayMask & OlDaysOfWeek.olSaturday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",SA"
    End If

    If Len(sDaysOfTheWeek) > 1 Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = Right(sDaysOfTheWeek, Len(sDaysOfTheWeek) - 1)
    End If

    ConvertDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek

End Function
```

When I step through the function in debug, I can see that the value passed into the function is 37.  Then, as I step through the code, I see that every If condition ends up true so at the end of the function, the string that gets returned is "SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA".

Obviously, I am not interrogating the passed value properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is a string concatenation operator in VB, so `37 & olSaturday` will be `"3764"`.

You need to use the `And` operator instead.

Answer (score 1):

The [& Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator) is for string concatenation in VBA. For the [RecurrencePattern.DayOfWeekMask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recurrencepattern.dayofweekmask) property you need to use boolean operators like AND, OR and etc. In the following case the appointment is displayed with the pattern: "Occurs every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday

```
.DayOfWeekMask = olMonday Or olTuesday Or olWednesday Or olThursday Or olFriday
```

So, to check whether it happens on a specific day of week you can use the AND operator:

```
Function ConvertDaysOfTheWeek(ByVal DayMask As Integer) As String

    Dim sDaysOfTheWeek As String
    sDaysOfTheWeek = ""

    If (DayMask AND OlDaysOfWeek.olSunday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = ",SU"
    End If

    If (DayMask AND OlDaysOfWeek.olMonday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",MO"
    End If
 
    If (DayMask AND OlDaysOfWeek.olTuesday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",TU"
    End If

    If (DayMask AND OlDaysOfWeek.olWednesday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",WE"
    End If

    If (DayMask AND OlDaysOfWeek.olThursday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",TH"
    End If
 
    If (DayMask AND OlDaysOfWeek.olFriday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",FR"
    End If
 
    If (DayMask AND OlDaysOfWeek.olSaturday) Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek + ",SA"
    End If

    If Len(sDaysOfTheWeek) > 1 Then
        sDaysOfTheWeek = Right(sDaysOfTheWeek, Len(sDaysOfTheWeek) - 1)
    End If

    ConvertDaysOfTheWeek = sDaysOfTheWeek

End Function
```

See [And Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator) for more information.